# Asymptotic estimate of the sum $\sum_{n\leq x}1/\phi^2(n)$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

How to show that we have the following estimate:
$$\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{\phi^2(n)}=c+O(\frac{1}{x}),$$
where $\phi$ is the [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) and $c$ is a constant. I tried to use the convolution method, but I don't know how to choose the appropriate functions.

Comment: try looking at the Euler product of $\sum_n \frac{1}{\phi^2(n)} n^{-s}$ to see where are its poles

Answer (score 2):

$\phi(n)$ is multiplicative and is never $0$, hence $\frac{1}{\phi^2(n)}$ is multiplicative :
$$\frac{1}{\phi(p^k)^2} = \frac{1}{(p-1)^2 p^{2(k-1)}} = \frac{p^2}{(p-1)^2} p^{-2k}$$

hence :

$$F(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\phi(n)^2}n^{-s} = \prod_p \left(1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\phi(p^k)^2}p^{-sk}\right) = \prod_p \left(1 + \frac{p^2}{(p-1)^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty p^{-(s+2)k}\right)$$

and since when $p \to \infty$ : $\frac{p^2}{(p-1)^2}  = 1 + \mathcal{O}(p^{-1})$  we find that

$$F(s) = \prod_p \left(1 + p^{-(s+2)} + \mathcal{O}(p^{-(s+3)})\right)$$

which converges absolutely for $Re(s +2) > 1$ i.e. for $Re(s) > -1$, hence, by a [general theorem on the speed of convergence of Dirichlet series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Dirichlet_series#Abscissa_of_convergence) :

$$\sum_{n \le x} \frac{1}{\phi(n)^2} = \mathcal{O}(x^{-1+\epsilon}) + F(0) \qquad\qquad \forall \ \epsilon > 0$$

to prove that $\sum_{n \le x} \frac{1}{\phi(n)^2} = \mathcal{O}(x^{-1+\epsilon}) + F(0)$ we need a further step :

**$F(s)$ has a simple pole at $s = -1$ and no other pole on $Re(s) = -1$** (because it is similar to $\zeta(s)$ on $Re(s) = 1$) hence it is true that :

$$\sum_{n \le x} \frac{1}{\phi(n)^2} = \mathcal{O}(x^{-1}) + F(0)$$

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see why the theorem implies the desired estimate. Could you write some details?

Comment: @XiangYu :  the theorem says that the abscissa of convergence of $F(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}$ (if  it is $< 0$) is given by $\sigma = \lim_{K \to \infty} \sup_{N \ge K}\frac{\ln |\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n|}{\ln N}$. here $a_n = 1/\phi(n)^2$ and $\sigma = -1$

Comment: @XiangYu : I just saw a problem, I added a step

Comment: $F(s)$ has a simple pole at $s=-1$ and not other pole on $\mathrm{Re}(s)=-1$, but why does it imply that we can send $\varepsilon$ to zero, it there something missing?

Comment: a simple pole at $s=-1$ and no other pole on $Re(s) = -1$ means that $\sum_n (a_n - F(0) n^{-2}) n^{-s}$ has no pole on $Re(s) \ge -1$

Comment: Note that $F(s)$ is a Dirichlet series with non-negative coefficients, and we see from the Euler product expansion $F(s)$ diverges at $s=-1$. By Landau's lemma, $F(s)$ cannot be analytically continued to any neighborhood of $s=-1$, it seems meaningless to say that $F(s)$ has a simple pole at $s=-1$.